# Cannot go from Eclipse window to any other window without minimizing Eclipse first. Any solution?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

When I work in Eclipse (java editor), Eclipse window seems modal - I cannot ALT+TAB to other applications (I'm on Win 10). I cannot go to other apps by clicking their icons on Windows taskbar. Besides, when I start my code by CTRL+F11, window of my JavaFX app also is not seen.

I have to minimize Eclipse first and only then I can ALT+TAB to another window (or click icon of that window)  - now that Eclipse is minimized, it works!

**Is there eclipse settings that fixes this annoying behaviour? And why is it this way by default?**

Comment: This was a known bug with Eclipse - as answered below, ctrl + alt + esc disables the 'always on top' mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open eclipse and press `ctrl+alt+esc`. It disables the 'always on top' behavior.